# Using post-stratification weights in R survey package

Tags: r, survey, stratification, survey-weights, survey-sampling

I am analyzing a dataset that has a variable for post-stratification weights. As this is a complex survey, the plan is to use the R `survey` package. I have been reading its documentation and feel like able to set a survey design correctly. So far, so good. That said, one aspect is still not clear for me.

Lumley says that `survey` assumes weights are *sampling* weights -- i.e. 1/(prop of selection for that observation):

> Survey designs are specified using the svydesign function. The main arguments to the the function are id to specify sampling units (PSUs and optionally later stages), strata to specify strata, **weights to specify sampling weights**, and fpc to specify finite population size corrections. These arguments should be given as formulas, referring to columns in a data frame given as the data argument. (http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/example-design.html)

My dataset does not include a variable for sampling weights. Its weight is a post-stratification weight accounting for probability of selection, unit non-responses, and post-stratifies the sample to match the age and gender joint distribution. The post-stratification weight is rescaled to sample size -- there are 1,000 observations so `sum(poststratification.wt)`=1,000, ranging from ~0.9 to ~5.5. I have closely inspected the data and the info available does not allow me to estimate the probability weights from the scratch.

So my question is: Am I safe, or roughly safe, using the provided post-stratification weight in the `svydesign(weights=)` argument? If not, what should I do? (Running a 1,000 survey is out of my budget possibility, hehe).

Answer (score 8):

If people *say* they have post-stratified weights, it does not necessarily mean they implemented post-stratification, proper (as in, rescaled the weights in each demographic cell to the known population total). About 80% of usage that I hear of "post-stratified weights" actually refers to *calibrated* weights (i.e., rather than trying to adjust each and every cell in a five-way table, the weights are only adjusted to match each of the five variables of the table individually). I produced what somebody referred to as a [methodological rant](https://www.surveypractice.org/article/2809-post-stratification-or-non-response-adjustment) on the distinction. The distinction, however, plays a role in standard error calculations, as Anthony noted in [another answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/147012/5739). With properly post-stratified weights, you can apply the regular variance estimation formulae, more or less treating your post-strata as sampling strata (minor technicalities aside). With weights that are only calibrated on each table margin, computations are somewhat more involved. Both procedures are internalized in `survey` package, anyway, though. You just need to feed your post-stratification/calibration variables to the appropriate design object/formula.

```
library(survey)
data(api)
# cross-classified post-stratification variable in population
apipop$stype.sch.wide <- 10*as.integer(apipop$stype) +
as.integer(apipop$sch.wide)
# cross-classified post-stratification variable in sample
apiclus1$stype.sch.wide <- 
  10*as.integer(apiclus1$stype) + as.integer(apiclus1$sch.wide)
# population totals
(pop.totals <- xtabs(~stype.sch.wide, data=apipop))
# reference design
dclus1 <- svydesign(id=~dnum,weights=~pw,data=apiclus1,fpc=~fpc)
# post-stratification of the original design
dclus1p <- postStratify(dclus1,~stype.sch.wide, pop.totals)
# design with post-stratified weights, but no evidence of post-stratification
dclus1pfake <- svydesign(id=~dnum,weights=~weights(dclus1p),data=apiclus1,fpc=~fpc)
# taking off the design with known weights, add post-stratification interaction
dclus1pp <- postStratify(dclus1pfake,~stype.sch.wide, pop.totals)

# estimates and standard errors: starting point
svymean(~api00,dclus1)
# post-stratification reduces standard errors a bit
svymean(~api00,dclus1p)
# but here we are not aware of the survey being post-stratified
svymean(~api00,dclus1pfake)
# if we just add post-stratification variables to the design object
# that only had post-stratified weights, the result is the same
# as for post-stratified object based on the original weights
svymean(~api00,dclus1pp)
```

Comment: could you please add an updated link for your linked "methodological rant"? (I'm presuming it's [https://www.surveypractice.org/article/2809-post-stratification-or-non-response-adjustment])

Comment: Yes, that is the correct link. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 6):

As @StasK says, the correct standard errors for raked/calibrated weights depend on the original weights and the auxiliary variables, and you don't get the right standard errors just by treating them as sampling weights.  Even post-stratification can be problematic if clusters are split between post-strata.

You don't actually need the original weights if you have the auxiliary variables.  You can recalibrate the weights in the `survey` package. The weights won't change -- they were already calibrated -- but the standard error estimates resulting from them will change.  There's a nice example of this in the [PEAS exemplars](https://www.restore.ac.uk/PEAS/exemplar1.php) created by Gillian Raab

It's pretty common in official statistics, though, to treat calibrated weights as if they were sampling weights.  That's what NHANES and BRFSS public-use datasets do, and pretty much any other large survey with public use data.  Until recently, users wouldn't have had software for doing it right.  So, it's not 'best practice', but it probably qualifies as 'good enough practice'

Answer (score 3):

bad news :)  your standard errors, confidence intervals, and tests of significance will be incorrect if you do not account for the relationship between the original and post-stratified weights.

i believe you can back-calculate the original sampling weights *if* you have the sampling clusters (although you'd have to invest a lot of time reversing the method in the `postStratify` command).

rather than spending more money, ask whoever creates this data to provide both sets of weights.  this is information that the original survey administrator has, and can send to you for the price of an e-mail.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Anthony Damico. That's sort of what I expected to hear but still had a last hope of being told otherwise :) I've been in contact with the survey team, hoping they provide me the information I need to either estimate the sampling weights or enter as fpc variables.

Comment: It's pretty standard in official statistics and public opinion research to just treat post-stratified weights as sampling weights. This is conservative, but typically not very

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the question:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/vignettes/precalibrated.pdf

> "Public-use data sets often come with weights that have been adjusted by post-stratification, raking, or calibration. It is standard practice to ignore this fact and treat the weights as if they were sampling weights. An alternative approach is to calibrate the weights again in R......"