# Calibration based on the total of a variable other than the population

Tags: r, survey

I've been working on some survey data using the `survey` package. I read the documentation [available](https://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/example-poststrat.html) on post-stratification and calibration, however I got stuck trying to calibrate the sampling weights on a total known for the population that is not the population total.

To make my self clear I prepared an example: Let's say I have income information for a sample stratified by sex, which lets me create the `svydesign` object:

```
data = data.frame(id = c(1:5),
              sex = c("F","F","F","C","C"),
              income = c(100,150,75,200,100),
              sw = c(2,2,3,3,3))

dis = svydesign(ids = ~id,
                strata = ~ sex,
                weights = ~sw,
                data = data)
```

Then I can calculate the total income by sex with:

```
    svyby(~income,~ sex,dis,svytotal)

  gender income        se
F      F    725  90.13878
M      M    900 300.00000
```

However, I don't know how many males or females are in the population but I do know total income by sex:

```
  gender income
     F    800
     M    800
```

I haven't been able to find a way of using the `calibrate` or `postStratify` functions to get this estimations of the totals by sex correctly with the se = 0 (i.e. calibrating(post-stratifying) a survey design with a total different from the total population by group).

I know I could calibrate the sampling weights by multiplying by the ratio calibration factor (dividing the estimated total over the population known total by sex). This approach has some limitations as stated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146841/using-post-stratification-weights-in-r-survey-package/540570#540570), since I would get the point estimations right but not the standard errors.

Thanks in advance for reading this! Any suggestions would be appreciated. :)